# Is that possible to call a Win-form in Panel

Tags: c#, winforms, panel

I am new on C# & I am developing a desktop application where I need to call a form inside a panel that already existing in form 
Lets say 
Form 1 -> Panel & button

Click on button

Form 2 appear in Form 1-> panel

Will someone help me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Adding a Form as a child of another control is not allowed. I think what you need is to create a UserControl and add the UserControl as a child of the panel.

Create your form (Form1) with a button (Button1) and a Panel (panel1).

Then create a UserControl (UserControl1). This is instead of your 'Form 2'.

In the click event handler for Button1 you add the following code:

```
private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    // Check that nothing has been added yet.
    if (panel1.Controls.Count == 0)
    {
        UserControl1 uc1 = new UserControl1();
        uc1.Dock = DockStyle.Fill;
        panel1.Controls.Add(uc1);
    }
}
```

Comment: Yes, it's allowed. You just need to set its `TopLevel` property to `false`, transforming it in a UserControl (give or take). A UserControl is however a better choice.

Comment: It was kind of funny though :-). Learned something new today.

Answer (score 1):

Add a panel to Form1 and call this code somewhere (e.g. in button click handler) in Form1:

```
Form2 form2 = new Form2() { TopLevel = false };
form2.Show();
panel.Controls.Add(form2);
```

Comment: I would not recommend this but you can even add form2.FormBorderStyle = FormBorderStyle.None; to get rid of the window border and the window controls. Then it looks exaclt like my UserControl answer.